# preferred_username claim missing from Google's profile scope

Tags: google-oauth

I am using Google OAuth API to do a SSO on a web app. I went to Google Cloud console > APIs & Services > OAuth consent screen > picked openid, profile, email as the scope.

From my web app to create a user using Google OAuth for SSO, it cannot find the preferred_username.

What am I missing with my OAuth consent scopes?